# Gradle error after i include some library (Shared_preference)

Tags: gradle, flutter, dart

I've a very simple flutter app which want to use shared_preference lib. Before i include it in my app, it able to build, But i receive errors from gradle after i installed in.

Error:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\Relaxion\flutter-app-arthas\flutter_app_arthas\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'D:\Relaxion\flutter-app-arthas\flutter_app_arthas\android\settings.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> Project with path ':name' could not be found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: D:\Relaxion\flutter-app-arthas\flutter_app_arthas\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  rxdart: ^0.20.0
  font_awesome_flutter: 8.0.1
  flutter_tags: ^0.3.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+2
```

Buildscript in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}
```

Last would be gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

I've tried upgrade gradle version to greater 1 but still doesn't work as expected. Any idea i could fix this?

Comment: i suppose the differences is come from app/android/settings.gradle: LINE 14

`
from     project(":name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
to         project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up create a new project and copy paste the whole android folder to my previous project and everything works !

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `gradle` version:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' //HERE
    }
}
```

to `3.3.0` or `3.0.1` or `3.4.1`.